# Trying to limit a parent row

Tags: mysql, rows

im trying to limit a parent row only.
I have that query

```
    SELECT
  comment.id user_id,
  comment.comment,
 comment.reply_id reply_id,
    comment.user_id,
u.image image,
u.group gg2,
comment.edited,
comment.deleted,
u.id idd2,
g.verified verified,
comment.date,
u.login,
comment.news_id
FROM (SELECT c.*
      FROM comments AS c
      WHERE c.news_id = 16
      ORDER BY c.id DESC
      LIMIT 0, 15) AS base
LEFT JOIN comments AS comment ON (
                    comment.reply_id = base.id
                    OR comment.id = base.id
                )
LEFT JOIN users u ON comment.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN groups g ON u.group = g.id
ORDER BY comment.id DESC
```

I want to limit only parents not childs.

This query work but its not optimal.
I have 4 million rows and this query take 105.1980 seconds.

I have indexes on reply_id, id, user_id and news_id.
Can you help me, to optimize it?

Example LIMIT 4 parents (reply_id):

```
+-------------+----------------------+----------+
| id          | comment              | reply_id |
+-------------+----------------------+----------+
|           1 | Sample Text          |     0    |
|           2 | Sample Text          |     0    |
|           3 | Sample Text          |     0    |
|           4 | Sample Text          |     0    |
|           5 | Sample Text          |     1    |
|           6 | Sample Text          |     1    |
|           7 | Sample Text          |     4    |
|           8 | Sample Text          |     2    |
|           9 | Sample Text          |     3    |
|          10 | Sample Text          |     3    |
+-------------+----------------------+----------+
```

Comment: this is a limit of this kind of database, with big data I don't think you will be able to have some kind of usable query... neo4j (for reading)
Back to the question, you should add the table structure and what you want exactly to do that, by now, is not too clear

Comment: Done, i add a example

Answer (score 0):

Limiting this will not make it faster: The order by on comment_id is (one) of your limiting factors for performance.

To add a limit:

```
SELECT
comment.id user_id,
comment.comment,
comment.reply_id reply_id,
comment.user_id,
u.image image,
u.group gg2,
comment.edited,
comment.deleted,
u.id idd2,
g.verified verified,
comment.date,
u.login,
comment.news_id
FROM (SELECT c.*
  FROM comments AS c
  WHERE c.news_id = 16
  ORDER BY c.id DESC
  LIMIT 0, 15) AS base
LEFT JOIN comments AS comment FORCE INDEX (idx_comment_nn_1) ON 
                comment.reply_id = base.id
                OR comment.id = base.id
LEFT JOIN users u ON comment.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN groups g ON u.group = g.id
ORDER BY comment.id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Adding this index might make it a bit quicker:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_comment_nn_1 ON comments(id DESC);
```

An explain plan  will have to show you if it is used.

Comment: Thanks for help,
Your query take 121.1210 seconds.

btw i have limit "0, 15" (15 is number of limited parents)

Comment: Did you add the index? Can you run an explain: explain {then here all your query};

Comment: Yes i added the index. 
`id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 PRIMARY <derived2> ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 15 Using temporary; Using filesort
1 PRIMARY comment ALL PRIMARY,Comments check (add comment),reply_id,idx_... NULL NULL NULL 4178211 Range checked for each record (index map: 0x33)
1 PRIMARY u eq_ref PRIMARY,id,id_2 PRIMARY 4 fotex.comment.user_id 1 NULL
1 PRIMARY g eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4 fotex.u.group 1 NULL
2 DERIVED c ref Comments count (NEWS) Comments count (NEWS) 4 const 32 Using where`

Sorry, i dont know how to create a table there.

Comment: Ok, it is not using the index.  Lets assume this is the slow part:

**SELECT c.*
  FROM comments AS c
  WHERE c.news_id = 16
  ORDER BY c.id DESC
  LIMIT 0, 15**. Can you benchmark that part and run an explain just for that?

Comment: `id
select_type
table
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
Extra
1
SIMPLE
c
ref
Comments count (NEWS)
Comments count (NEWS)
4
const
32
Using where`

Query take 0.0006 seconds.

Comment: Can you align that (edit your post)? I can not read this comment properly.

Comment: Also make a screenshot of the previous explain of the full query please

Comment: Ok, the **LEFT JOIN comments AS comment** is causing the real problem. The index on ID is present. Two things which can be done: Rewrite the OR into two joins, or see what a FORCE index does: Please run an explain on the new query in the post.

Comment: http://puu.sh/j2NKa/66dae41caa.png - Query take 15 Seconds, better but still too long

Comment: Hey, that is about 85% better already :), but most likely due to caching.

Comment: Yes, but page is loaded in 15 seconds XD

Comment: Ok, you will have to refactor your query so that: **LEFT JOIN comments AS comment FORCE INDEX (idx_comment_nn_1) ON 
                comment.reply_id = base.id
                OR comment.id = base.id** becomes two left joins (1 for each or), and then use a WHERE statement to sort out which data to keep. That hopefully gets you to a 0.0006 total for the query.

Comment: Ok, I said: **You** will have to refactor the query ... I did not change anything anymore: That refactor needs a lot more time then I can spend right here as volunteer.